# Unable to ping from one project to another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I create two instances in GCP in two different projects. I able to ping from one project to another project with external ip but unable to ping with internal ip. Is there any way to set a connection between the two porojects

Answer (score 1):

The internal IP are link to the project vpc. Thereby, 2 different project, 2 different vpc. And thus internal network are strongly isolated.

You have several solution for creating a bridge between vpc and reach the VM with the internal ip;:

- [Vpc peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering)
- [Shared vpc](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc)
- [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview)